# Rotate image or div when nav is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

I've been searching for a way to rotate an image a div say 90 degrees when a link is clicked, but can not seem to get it to at all. Here is some code I'm trying at the moment amongst many others, using the jQuery Rotate plugin.

```
$('#canvas a').click(function() {
    $('#circle').rotateLeft([angle=90]);
    return false;
});
```

I can get it to kind of work with css3, although it doesn't animate, and it only rotates once. I would like to keep rotating each time a link is clicked.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#canvas a").click(function(){
        $('#circle img').css({"-webkit-transform" : "rotate(45deg)"})
    });     
 });
```

Comment: [This site](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animations/) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Seems to be on the right track although I can't see how to bind that kind of animation to a click on a different element.

Comment: I think you add/remove a class to achieve that

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/C5tDu/3/

the key css is the following:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **+** operator before rotation value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#canvas a").click(function(){
            $('#circle img').css({"-webkit-transform" : "rotate(+=45deg)"})
        });     
 });
```

Comment: Tried this although it still only happens once and does not animate.